# Beamer: TOC for each section starting from the second

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

What the title says.

In the slides below, I want to put a TOC in the default state at the beginning. But the `\AtBeginSection` setting will add another TOC just right after it, for the section 1. How can we have `\AtBeginSection` , but only from the 2nd section?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\AtBeginSection[]{
    \begin{frame}<beamer>
        \frametitle{Outline}
        \tableofcontents[currentsection]
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}
\frame{ \frametitle{Outline} \tableofcontents }
\section{Section 1}
\frame{\frametitle{Frame 1}}
\section{Section 2}
\frame{\frametitle{Frame 2}}
\section{Section 3}
\frame{\frametitle{Frame 3}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using the `ifthen`package

```
\usepackage{ifthen}
\AtBeginSection[]{
   \ifthenelse{\thesection > 1}{
    \begin{frame}<beamer>
        \frametitle{Outline}
        \tableofcontents[currentsection]
    \end{frame}
    }
}
```